# Why animation's Setspeedratio function is not work at first time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, storyboard

I have a WPF Application. In my application, I moving trains in animation. I want to change animations speed when I want.

I used below function to change the speed of animation.

```
 Storyboard.SetSpeedRatio(this,NewSpeed);
```

I wrote this method for change the speed of all storyboard object.

```
private void storyboardSetSpeed(double speed)
    {
        foreach (Storyboard sb in Resources.Values.OfType<Storyboard>())
        {
            sb.SetSpeedRatio(this, speed);
        }
    }
```

When I click the play button, I'm calling above function. But It's not effecting the storyboard at first click. When I pause and than click resume button, The storyboard speed changing clearly.

Why I can't change the storyboard's speed at first time?

Comment: I have a thought, is it possible in Your app that you can re-load that animation with new speed ? I mean not only to change speed, but when You click play button to re-load animation with new speed.

Comment: @KubaDo When I click play button, I'm loading the animations already. So this is not answer.